# Please help with getting Steam to run on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, steam, error-handling

I am trying to get Steam running, but I keep getting this error in the terminal.  Can someone please help me?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 :  Depends:  libglapi-meea:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4)
    unoty-control-center :  Depends:  libcheese-gtk23  (>= 3.4.0) but is not going to be installed 
    Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but is not going to be installed 
    E: Error, pkgProblemResolver: : Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
    press return to continue:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck my friend. I have installed Ubuntu over the weekend and run into 10000 problems, one of which was this exact issue.  I used these set of commands below to make it work. It's important that you follow the order that I issue the commands & also that you modify where it says "johnsmith" to your username within your home directory.

```
rm -rf ~/.steam
rm -rf ~/.local/share/Steam
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

Now you need to run steam so that it downloads the files. You then need to modify one of the files it installs with the commands below.

```
cd /home/johnsmith/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
```

That's it. If you couldn't navigate to the directory, I've seen some users say that the final file is located in the directory below instead.

```
 cd /home/johnsmith/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Please up vote me if this helped you.